# How to make ardrone_autonomy work on ROS Melodic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to control an AR Drone from a Jetson Nano which has Ubuntu 18 (ROS Melodic), and I can not compile the ardrone_autonomy package, because when I try, it gives me the next errors:

```
Base path: /home/jetson/ardrone_ws Source space: /home/jetson/ardrone_ws/src Build space: /home/jetson/ardrone_ws/build Devel space: /home/jetson/ardrone_ws/devel Install space: /home/jetson/ardrone_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jetson/ardrone_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/jetson/ardrone_ws/build"
#### [  1%] Performing update step for 'ardronelib' [  2%] Performing configure step for 'ardronelib' No configure [  2%] Built target
_ardrone_a

utonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_hdvideo_stream
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_zimmu_3000
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector31
[  2%] Performing build step for 'ardronelib'
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
Libs already extracted
Building target static
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_kalman_pressure
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_LedAnim
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_time
[  2%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Architecture aarch64 is already built
Creating universal static lib file from architectures aarch64
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_perf
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_detect
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_rc_references
Build done.
Building ARDroneTool/Lib
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_CamSelect
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wifi
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_of
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_raw_measures
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pressure_raw
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_gyros_offsets
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_altitude
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_RecordEnable
[  2%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wind_speed
cc video_mem32.c
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_euler_angles
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_magneto
/tmp/cc159hYQ.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc159hYQ.s:130: Error: unknown mnemonic `bswap' -- `bswap x3'
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_demo
generic.makefile:231: recipe for target '../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/vlib_PROD_MODE_Linux_4.9.140-tegra_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_7.4.0/video_mem32.o' failed
make[8]: *** [../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/vlib_PROD_MODE_Linux_4.9.140-tegra_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_7.4.0/video_mem32.o] Error 1
vlib.makefile:104: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[7]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'build_vlib' failed
make[6]: *** [build_vlib] Error 2
Makefile:170: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[5]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:84: recipe for target 'build_libs' failed
make[4]: *** [build_libs] Error 2
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target '/home/jetson/ardrone_ws/devel/src/ardronelib-stamp/ardronelib-build' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jetson/ardrone_ws/devel/src/ardronelib-stamp/ardronelib-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2963: recipe for target 'ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix33
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_phys_measures
[  2%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

As much as I know it is a problem of using ardrone_autonomy package in ROS Melodic, and I couldn't find any solutions, so any help would be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329327/how-to-make-ardrone_autonomy-work-on-ros-melodic?/) by [new_wanderer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44299/new_wanderer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358653/how-to-make-ardrone-autonomy-package-work-on-jetson-nano/57475620#57475620).

**26.04.2021 EDIT:**  Only the first two steps are sufficient for making it work in ROS Melodic, the rest of the steps are important only if you try this on a Jetson. Also you can take an already working docker container with everything inside: `docker pull funderburger/ardrone_autonomy_ros_ubuntu_16:latest` (some more info [here.](https://github.com/Funderburger/Hallway-self-driving-drone) )

EDIT:

So, basically, the answer I found it is not exactly what I want, because that guy use a docker container, but for now it works. So the steps I followed are exactly this (in case the page disappears):

1. I downloaded the docker image using:

   `sudo docker pull ros:kinetic-robot-xenial`

And then followed this steps to run the image: [http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker][1]

2. Then I cloned the ardrone_autonomy package in a worksapce, from the above link:

> ```
>  mkdir -p catkin_ws/src
>  cd catkin_ws/src
>  git clone https://github.com/dsapandora/ardrone_autonomy.git
>  apt-get update
>  cd ../
>  rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
>  catkin_make
> ```

3. After the error with `bswap` appears, edit this file:  `devel/src/ardronelib/ARDroneLib/VP_SDK/VP_Os/linux/intrin.h` and replace:

.

```
 static INLINE uint32_t _byteswap_ulong(uint32_t value)
    {
      __asm("bswap %0":
          "=r" (value):
          "0" (value));
    
      return value;
    }
```

with this:

```
static INLINE uint32_t _byteswap_ulong(uint32_t value)
{
  int32_t tmp;

  __asm __volatile(
    "eor        %1, %2, %2, ror #16\n"
    "bic        %1, %1, #0x00ff0000\n"
    "mov        %0, %2, ror #8\n"
    "eor        %0, %0, %1, lsr #8"
    : "=r" (value), "=r" (tmp)
    : "r" (value)
  );

  return value;
}
```

and comment this line: `_BitScanReverse(&index, code);`

4. After you do this if you try to give it a `catkin_make` it should appear the last error which can be resolved by replacing this line (from the same file as above):

`"mov        %0, %2, ror #8\n"`

with:

`"mov        %0, %2\n"`

and now should work just fine.

---

Originally posted by [new_wanderer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44299/new_wanderer/) with karma: 56 on 2019-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-13**:
Can you please update your solution with the relevant steps? Linked pages can and often do disappear (even from Stack Overflow)